# is there a way to use the whole width of a cell in UITableView while keeping scrolling ability

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I use `UITableView's` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to display the data (`NSString*`) by assigning `cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Everything is fine but I need to color certain lines, so I use `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor` and `cell.textLabel.textColor`. The colored lines look a bit ugly - they have blank space at the beginning and at the end (both are roughly 1 char wide). Maybe these are reserved for scrolling marker (up/down)? Is there a way to use the whole width of the cell while keeping scrolling ability up? Any special style or flag? Thanks. Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label does not fill the entire cell, so setting its background colour will not cover everything.

Set the cell's background colour instead, but this has to be done in the willDisplayCell: delegate method, not cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (see the docs for details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell

Comment: Thank you jrturton, I am to try it tomorrow. Regards,